# Date picker to PHP to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a page whereon users must choose a starting date through jQuery DateTimePicker. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
  <div data-min-view="2" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyy" 
       class="input-group date datetimepicker col-md-5 col-xs-7">
    <input name="of_datefrom" size="16" class="form-control" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary">
      <i class="icon-th mdi mdi-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My column for *of_datefrom* is in `datetime` format.

Now I want the user to pick a date in format *dd-mm-yyy* in HTML and have this value stored in SQL as *YYYY-mm-dd G:i:s* where G:i:s should be in format 23:59:59 with a constant value of 00:00:00. By this I mean I need the user to choose a day from a month in a year only and have the 00:00:00 added automatically in the Database.

This is what I tried so far but doesn't seem to be working:

```
$of_datefrom = $_POST['of_datefrom'];
$of_datefrom=date("dd-mm-YYYY",strtotime($of_datefrom));
```

Comment: MySql will add 00:00:00 in datetime when you put just date

Comment: So how do I transform the HTML input dd-mm-yyyy format to the PHP YYYY-mm-dd format with the datetimepicker?

Comment: In PHP is `$of_datefrom=date("d-m-Y", strtotime($of_datefrom));`